# radio button switches on 2 clicks

Tags: angular, typescript, radio-button

There is a radio button for sexes and when first I choose male it works fine, but the second time i click male it jumps to female. Also this happens the other way around.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="employee.listingRule.includes('is_female')" >
    <label class="col-12 col-md-3 pb-2 col-form-label">sex:</label>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-9 pb-2">
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6">
            <fa-icon class="mr-2"
            [icon]="!employee.is_female ? icon.radioSelected : icon.radioBlank"
            (click)="setSex()"></fa-icon>
            <span (click)="setSex()">
              Man
             </span>
           </div>
           <div class="col-6">
             <fa-icon class="mr-2"
               [icon]="employee.is_female ? icon.radioSelected : icon.radioBlank"
               (click)="setSex()"></fa-icon>
               <span (click)="setSex()">
                 Women
               </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is a snippet of the code, a function that I use

```
  setSex() {
    this.employee.is_female = !this.employee.is_female;
  }
```

How can i fix it so that on the second click it doesn't jump to the other sex?

Comment: Where is the radio button in your code ?, you should use `change` event instead of `click` on radio buttons

Comment: Why don't you use a standardized `<input type="radio>` with custom styling?

Comment: On every click you change the sex, regardless of the button pressed. If you want to keep your implementation like this, pass the sex of the button clicked (e.g. `(click)="setSex('male')"`) and react to that in your function accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better option is passing male or female in method and activate based on that 
(click)="setGender('male')" or (click)="setGender('female')"